# Supermarket chains that you can / cannot buy Chometz in right after Pesach

Tags: passover, food, halacha

Which supermarket chains are there no issues regarding Chometz Sheovar Alav HaPesach? And which are problematic?

Comment: I don't know how all of the operative business models are set up, but isn't this almost always (>99%) answered on a store-by-store basis?

Comment: @WAF I think that at least some stores are owned by a national corporation rather than franchised to individual owners. Walmart, for example. For these, it should be possible to answer this question.

Comment: Gershon I am guessing this answer is for you

http://matzav.com/lakewood-shoprite-to-remain-open-24-hours-following-yom-tov-2

Comment: At least it's all vadai yashan!

Comment: 99Cent Stores are Jewish owned and do not sell their Chametz. I think there might also be an issue with Smart & Final.

Comment: @SethJ You can start a bounty if you want for "Current Answers are Outdated".

Comment: @DoubleAA, wouldn't it be good to keep it current?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My understanding (no source) is that all of the [Schnucks](http://www.schnucks.com/) stores are owned by gentiles.

[The Star-K's 2011 guide](http://www.star-k.org/cons-pesach-flash.htm), q.v., lists national chains okay to buy from after *yom tov*.

Comment: @msh210 Superfresh buys from C&S, per the C&S website (http://www.cswg.com/top-customers). I do not know why Superfresh is listed in the approved stores list.

Comment: Actually, Superfresh is not on the actual list currently appearing on the Star-K's website (although I saw it on a community-circulated version of the list earlier).  Perhaps they removed it and updated the list.

Comment: To close the loop, it was announced in my Shul this past Shabbath that Superfresh is a problem, due to their distributor (C&S).

Comment: By the way, just because Schnucks is owned by non-Jews does not obviate the problem of the distributor. As of last year (I haven't heard yet or checked this year) many publicly traded and non-Jewish owned businesses were problematic because they ordered products from C&S, which is a large but privately held food distribution company owned by Jews, and its/their Hametz is not sold for Pesah.

Comment: In past years, Rabbi Teitz of Elizabeth, NJ, sold all of the chametz owned by C&S.  If he does it again this year, then there is no problem whatsoever to buy chametz after Pesach from any C&S client store, assuming the store itself is owned by non-Jews.

Answer (score 1):

In the northeast US, the Jewish-owned [C & S](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%26S_Wholesale_Grocers) Wholesale (Cohen & Siegel) is a large distributor of food to many supermarkets. One should buy chametz that was either acquired by the gentile-owned supermarket before pesach or by C&S after pesach. One can also buy from Jewish stores that sell their chametz over Pesach.

Comment: Do you have information on which stores buy from C&S and any more detailed guidance about timing?

Comment: @R'Isaac Moses: IIRC the Star-K publication I linked to in my answer discusses timing. @R'Ari, re "One can also buy from Jewish stores that sell their chametz over Pesach": Presumably the problem of a Jewish-owned distributor that does not sell its _chametz_ applies equally to a Jewish-owned retailer as to a gentile-owned retailer, no? Your warning "One should buy chametz that was either acquired by the gentile-owned supermarket before pesach or by C&S after pesach" would then apply to Jewish-owned retailers also, whereas you make it sound as though it does not.

Comment: C & S Has a list of their top customers here:
http://www.cswg.com/top-customers.

Comment: It was started by 2 Jews Cohen & Siegel, and Cohen's grandson is the current CEO. I doubt that it is fully Jeiwsh-owned though, so that might make a difference.

Comment: In past years, Rabbi Teitz of Elizabeth, NJ, sold all of the chametz owned by C&S. If he does it again this year, then there is no problem whatsoever to buy chametz after Pesach from any C&S client store, assuming the store itself is owned by non-Jews.

Comment: I wasn't aware of this, though I don't know if its so easy to sell all the merchandise in a business while they continue selling it as usual.